# Why is the remove function not working for hashmaps?

Tags: java

I am working on a simple project that obtains data from an input file, gets what it needs and prints it to a file. I am basically getting word frequency so each key is a string and the value is its frequency in the document. The problem however, is that I need to print out these values to a file in descending order of frequency. After making my hashmap, this is the part of my program that sorts it and writes it to a file.

```
//Hashmap I create
Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
int valueMax = -1;
//function to sort hashmap
while (map.isEmpty() == false){
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()){
                if (entry.getValue() > valueMax){
                    max = entry.getKey();
                    System.out.println("max: " + max);
                    valueMax = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("value: " + valueMax);
                }
            }
            map.remove(max);
            out.write(max + "\t" + valueMax + "\n");
            System.out.println(max + "\t" + valueMax);  
        }
```

When I run this i get:

```
t 9
t 9
t 9
t 9
t 9
....
```

so it appears the remove function is not working as it keeps getting the same value. I'm thinking i have an issue with a scope rule or I just don't understand hashmaps very well.

If anyone knows of a better way to sort a hashmap and print it, I would welcome a suggestion.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because on every subsequent iteration, `entry.getValue() > valueMax` is never true because you don't reset `valueMax` on re-entry into the while loop.

You don't need to muck around with double-looping over a concurrently accessible map though.

[`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) has a [`lastKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html#lastKey%28%29) method that returns the greatest key and doesn't require iteration over the entire map.

Comment: Well that is alternative, but didn't answer why remove is not working!

Comment: A `TreeMap` implements the `SortedMap<K,V>` interface and doesn't have the synchronization overhead. Admittedly, the question is using a `ConcurrentHashMap` now, so there might be a need for that overhead, but I'd be aware of that.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, I assume that if the OP uses a concurrent map implementation it does so for a reason.

Comment: I need to sort by the frequency(value) not by the key. I will take a look at concurrentSkipListMap though

Comment: That's true. I guess I'm being pedantic, but any implementation of `SortedMap` would provide the `lastKey` method and a much cleaner implementation. The choice of which implementation (`TreeMap` versus `ConcurrentHashMap` versus a custom implementation) is an exercise left to the programmer.

Comment: By the way you are correct. I reset it and now it works. Sorry at first i misunderstood what you said and only noticed it when @mikej posted it again.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like you aren't resetting `valueMax` at the end of your loop. This means the first time round the loop you'll find the maximum but you'll never find any subsequent values because you'll still be comparing to the overall maximum.

Comment: Sadly I think this is the issue. Let me see if this fixes it

Answer (score 1):

Hashmap: no order. You can use ArrayList, which implements List to have an order.

Take a look : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: I needed to have a key value data collection which i didn't think I could implement with a ArrayList.

Comment: I mean just String[] = new String[number]; Then you put in "key,value", "key2,value2", etc. Then you can do your for and split on "," but sure, it is not the best solution but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because there no entries in map with key > initial value of valueMax, so condition `if (entry.getValue() > valueMax)` never true.

Additionally, there's `TreeMap` which holds it's contents sorted, so you can just iterate over it's `entrySet()` w/o any additional logic.

Comment: I have valueMax set to -1 when it starts. It get 2 or 3 other values before it settles on t = 9 so that shouldn't be the isue. As for treemap its sorting by the key instead of the value so while its nice and alphabetical, its not sorted by frequency.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like (not tested)

```
  final Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
  final Comparator <String, String> comparator = new Comparator ()
         {
             compare(String o1, String o2) 
             {
                  return map.get(o1) - map.get(o2);
             }
         };

  final TreeMap <String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap (comparator);
  sortedMap.addAll(map);
  System.out.println(sortedMap);
```